# Prevent PowerShell expression from clearing output

Tags: console, powershell-7

My PowerShell scripts executes towards its end an external executable using `Invoke-Expression`.

```
Invoke-Expression "$($config._resguy) $mapname -missing"
```

However, this clears from the console any previous output. How can I prevent that?